# Is there anyway—maybe with a batch file—to determine if PDF has odd number of pages, and if so add blank?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, batch

Every day I get a large number of PDF files (100+) I need to concat and duplex print. Unfortunately they don’t all have an even number of pages so the print doesn’t duplex correctly.

Is there a way in a batch file to look at the number of pages in a PDF and add a blank page if the PDF has an odd number of pages?

Comment: Is it an option not to concattenate all PDFs and then print them, but to simply print them one by one? (IIRC just control-A on the folder, right click, print). That would print each file and start on a fresh paper for each file.

Comment: What are you using to concat the files?

Comment: @ Hennes   It is too time consuming to print them one by one.

Comment: @heavyd   We are using pdftk to concat them.

Answer (score 3):

[Sejda](http://sejda.org)'s console can help (disclaimer: I'm one of the developers):

```
./bin/sejda-console merge --addBlanks --directory my_files --output my_merged_files.pdf
```

The --addBlanks option will append a blank page if the number of pages in the pdf is odd.

This sample command merges all pdf files in the folder my_files.

Download the latest release from here: https://github.com/torakiki/sejda/releases

Hope it helps!